# How to refresh List in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

```
private ObservableCollection<classType>_colls;
public ObservableCollection<classType> Colls
{
   get {return _colls;}
   set { _colls = value; OnPropertyChanged("Colls");}
}

public string _name;
public string Name
{
  get { return _name; }
  set { _name= value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
}

public string _Id;
public string Id
{
    get { return _Id; }
    set { _Id= value; OnPropertyChanged("Id"); }
}
```

I have a List control and `ItemsSource` bound with `ObservableCollection`.

After editing the value, the collection gets refreshed but the View's
property is not changed.

The `classType` contains 2 properties `Name` & `Id` and it extends `INotifyPropertyChanged`. But the value of the `Name` property is not affected in View.

The viewmodels:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class classType : ViewModelBase
{
    public string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }

    public string _Id;
    public string Id
    {
        get { return _Id; }
        set { _Id = value; OnPropertyChanged("Id"); }
    }
}
```

The XAML view:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Colls,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock
          ToolTip="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
          Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Try to have `updatesourcetrigger=propertychanged` in you view.  Also, make sure that you have set `Binding` as `Twoway`

Comment: Yes, i did that too, but not working

Comment: Show us the code of `ViewModel` and how you assigned the `DataContext`

Comment: Please explain, where `Name` and `Id` of your first code sample belong to... are they in the same class as the `Colls` property?

Comment: @All, Please, approve the suggested edit. I incorrectly voted for reject. My appologies

Answer (score 1):

Don't know where you went wrong.  It requires full code(both view and viewmodel) to find the root cause.  Let me give a working sample based on you code that will help you to debug yourself.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Colls,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock ToolTip="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Button Click="Button_Click" Width="100" Height="50" Content="Click Me" />
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Colls = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
        Colls.Add(new MyClass()
        {
            Id = "1", Name = "aaa"
        });
        Colls.Add(new MyClass()
        {
            Id = "2",
            Name = "bbb"
        });
        Colls.Add(new MyClass()
        {
            Id = "3",
            Name = "ccc"
        });

        this.DataContext = this;

    }

    private ObservableCollection<MyClass> _colls;
    public ObservableCollection<MyClass> Colls
    {
        get { return _colls; }
        set { _colls = value; }
    }

    private int i = 1;

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Colls[0].Name = "Value changed for " + i++ + " time(s).";
    }
```

**MyClass.cs**

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{       

    public string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }

    public string _Id;
    public string Id
    {
        get { return _Id; }
        set { _Id = value; OnPropertyChanged("Id"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propname)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propname));
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: `Colls` property should be either readonly or it should implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Otherwise fine

Comment: @Dinesh STOP posting your code in comments! You where notified about this an hour ago and you still do it again -.-

Answer (score 0):

As you know, databinding does not need manual refreshing command when ViewModel has bound properly.

Your properties in `classType` fires `PropertyChanges` well, but collection does not tell its internally fired event to outside. So a `Listview` which only to know outside events does not know changes. In order to fix this, `ObservableCollection` requires to bubble-up its contained property changes to `CollectionChanged` event.

To make it, I recommend you to use `ObservableCollectionEx` for that.

- Nuget package link: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ObservableCollectionEx/

Install above package and just replace `ObservableCollection` to `ObservableCollectionEx` in your ViewModel class then all set.

Comment: Wha's the problem of using ObservableCollection? If a collection that is bound to a list is modified (e.g. add/remove items) the UI *will* get updated.

Comment: Disagree.  `classType` already has `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented and that should do the trick.  `ObservableCollection` nothing to do here to notify internally on `Propertychanged`.  It should only notify for `CollectionChanged`.

Comment: @Gopichandar // sorry for misleading and thanks for pointing it out precisely. I'll fix description.

Comment: I also agree with @Gopichandar, It should be updated by the above code

Comment: @Hadi: i didn't use collection changed event to update the property. just cleared the collection and load the Collection from Api Service call

Comment: @Dinesh // did you set `Colls` in every refresh not by `Clear` but `new`? `Colls = new ObservableCollection<classtype>();` might not work as you expected. use `Colls.Clear();` instead.

Comment: @Youngjae: I'm sorry to say it, but your advices both in answer and comments are not very helpful. `ObservableCollectionEx` is of topic and using Clear instead of setting property does not solve anything, since he calls PropertyChanged in Colls' setter

Comment: @Liero // thanks. let me delete it or not till op gives any result as I still think my answer is in the boundary of op's problem. For me, calling Prop in ObservableCollection setter does not reflect contained property changes and my solution helps always (7 projects in years). maybe, my answer could be useful when it combined with MVVM-light.